# Get WET54G working with Airport Extreme Base Station with WPA2 Password

Tags: wifi, airport

I am attempting to get my Linksys (Cisco) WET54G Wireless Ethernet Bridge working on my Airport Extreme Base Station. I know you have to connect via ethernet and change your ip settings so you can connect to the device itself and get to its configuration page on Macs.

My problem is that while I can get on that page I don't think its ever authenticating. I have a WPA2 password set on my base station and it can detect it and I do chose the right type of password for WPA2 passwords on there, but no matter how patient I am in setting the password when I go to the status page I see absolutely no Wireless TX/RX whatsoever.

I did do a factory reset on it and keep setting it to my wireless network and configure the password, but it never seems to get onto my network. I also can't seem to get the updated firmware to upload. It says it uploads the file to the WET54G but it never successfully updates it.

It is just bizarre that I got this working fine on a less secure network in an apartment, but now I can't get this working at home on a more secure network. It also seems to do little odd things like even though in scanning for wifi networks it detects my network as being on Channel 7 when I go to the main setup page it shows Channel 6 there, odd.

Any ideas on what to do to get my Wireless Ethernet Bridge to play nice with my Airport Extreme Base Station?